# Using a different date in a shell script

Tags: shell, date

SO, I have a whole script that runs every hour with a date as input. Normally, it takes the current time, but now I need it to run for an interval of time in the past, every hour as well.

What I've done so far is:

```
 DEFINING THE OLD DATE
  8 start_date=20131218
  9 num_hours=5
 10 for i in `seq 1 $num_hours`
 11 do
 12     date=`date -d "${start_date}+${i} hours"` 
 13     echo $date # Use this however you want! 
 14 
  .
  .
  .
 25  done
```

The starting date is Dec 18, 2013 and then in each iteration it should give me one more hours from the starting time. This part I found it in another article here and it works. The problem  comes when I do

```
 echo $(date)
```

it prints the current time instead of the time that I previously defined. Of course any other variable that I define from the date has the values from the current time. For instance,

```
 18 datestamp=$(date +%F)
 19 hourstamp=$(date +%H)
```

I'm new in shell programming and I have no idea what to do. Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
18 datestamp=$(date -d "${start_date}+${i} hours" +%F)
19 hourstamp=$(date -d "${start_date}+${i} hours" +%H)
```

As @BMW said, try to avoid use the `date` as a variable name to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

$(date) will run the command `date` and export the result.
so when echo it, it will return current date/time.

Second, date is the unix command, avoid to use it as a variable. so this will fix your issue"

```
DATE=`date -d "${start_date}+${i} hours"` 
echo $DATE
```